# AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'xlabel'

Tags: python, matplotlib, attributeerror

My code is :

```
import matplotlib as plt 
sns.distplot(CMSU['Spending'], kde = False)
plt.xlabel("Spending", size=15)
plt.ylabel("Probablity", size=15)
plt.title("Distribution for the variable - Spending", size=18);
```

I am getting the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-1c6eb744a592> in <module>
      1 sns.distplot(CMSU['Spending'], kde = False)
----> 2 plt.xlabel("Spending", size=15)
      3 plt.ylabel("Probablity", size=15)
      4 plt.title("Distribution for the variable - Spending", size=18);

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'xlabel'
```

What possibly can go wrong?

Comment: Can you share how `plt` is created/initialized?

Comment: What's wrong, is that you forget to add the `import`s to the code posted. There you will see that you need to `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` and not something like `import matplotlib as plt`

Comment: @Mureinik  Yes. Here it is  : import matplotlib as plt

Comment: @JohanC Got it thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `import` statement is wrong. Those methods belong to `pyplot`. I.e., you should have imported it like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` rather than just `matplotlib as plt`, because `xlabel` and probably various other functions don't exist in matplotlib.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel()
```

Same for `ylabel` and `title`:

```
matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel()
matplotlib.pyplot.title()
```

Comment: `from matplotlib import pyplot as plt` is standard, and a lot easier

Comment: @MattDMo yes, and also `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` is used

Answer (score 0):

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 4>()
2 plt.title("Videos are strongly correlated with clicking")
3 plt.bar(["Page Load", "Video Watching", "Reading Pricing"], [-0.39, 0.67, 0.0004])
----> 4 plt.ylabl("Correlation With Clicking")

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'ylabl
i ran this same code before and it came out success
, wondering what's going on now!!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).